# Writing to texture in OpenGL 3.2 / GLSL 1.50 and then writing texture to screen

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader, fbo

I want to implement deferred shading in OpenGL.

I have a Framework supporting OpenGL. Forward Shading with a typical vertex shader and fragment shader works fine, scaling and transforming is no problem.

But implementing the deferred shading leads to the problem that I don't see anything and I don't know whether I write to my textures in my FBO or not.

In my render method I unbound the FBO to write directly to the screen. It works and everything looks great. But binding the FBO, writing to the textures and the try to write the textures to the screen just gives me a blank screen.

So my question is: Do I handle the parallel writing to different textures right?

The initialize method creates all shader programs and binds the VBOs to the inputs of the shaders.

The render method is separated into a deferred{} block and a non-deferred{} shader block. The non-deferred shading is a simple forward shading concept.

I use OpenGL 3.2 / GLSL 1.50.

Since GLSL 1.50 do not support layout(location), I think it should work with binding the fragment shader output to different colors (see the initialize() method).

Creating the buffers results in a successful GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE.

Below you find my initialize() method:

```
gettimeofday(&oldTime, NULL);

addLightToScene();

printError("Beginning of initialize");
/*
 * Enabling standard features in OpenGL
 */
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
// Solange die Normalen nicht genutzt werden, sollte openGL nicht selber entscheiden dürfen in welche Richtung ein Vertex zeigt...
//glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

/*
 * Create ID for texturing
 */
glGenTextures(1, &texture_ID);

/*
 *  Loading pixel- and vertex shader program and compile and link them
 */
createProgram(vertex_ID, pixel_ID, program_ID,
              "shaders//VertexShader.glsl", "shaders//FragmentShader.glsl");

glBindFragDataLocation(program_ID, 0, "fragColor");

glLinkProgram(program_ID);

printProgramInfoLog(program_ID);

/*
 * Get vertex attribute IDs and uniform IDs
 */
getAttributeLocation(inPosition_ID, program_ID, "in_position");

getAttributeLocation(inColor_ID, program_ID, "in_color");

getAttributeLocation(inTexCoord_ID, program_ID, "in_texcoord");

getAttributeLocation(inNormal_ID, program_ID, "in_normal");

getUniformLocation(lightPos_ID, program_ID, "light_position");

getUniformLocation(lightInt_ID, program_ID, "light_intensity");

getUniformLocation(lightAmb_ID, program_ID, "light_ambient");

getUniformLocation(mvpMatrix_ID, program_ID, "MVPMatrix");

getUniformLocation(viewportMatrix_ID, program_ID, "ViewportMatrix");

getUniformLocation(samplerTexture_ID, program_ID, "myTexture");

/*
 * Create VAO and VBOs
 */
glGenVertexArrays (1 , &VAO); // Erzeugen des VAOs
glBindVertexArray(VAO); // Zustandsautomat: Aktiviere das VAO
glGenBuffers(4, &VBO[0]); // Erzeugen der 4 VBOs

// vertex position --> vec4
bindBuffer(VAO, VBO[0], inPosition_ID, 4);
// vertex color --> vec3
bindBuffer(VAO, VBO[1], inColor_ID, 3);
// vertex normal --> vec3
bindBuffer(VAO, VBO[2], inNormal_ID, 3);
// vertex texture coordinates --> vec2
bindBuffer(VAO, VBO[3], inTexCoord_ID, 2);

cam_c = QVector3D(0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
cam_n = QVector3D(0.f, 0.f, -1.f);
cam_v = QVector3D(0.f, -1.f, 0.f);

oldCamRotX = 0;
oldCamRotY = 0;
oldCamDist = 0;

printError("End of linking forward shading program");

/*
 * Deferred shading from here
 */

// First stage program
createProgram(firstStageVertex_ID, firstStageFragment_ID, firstStageProgram_ID,
              "shaders//FirstStageVertexShader.glsl",
              "shaders//FirstStageFragmentShader.glsl");

// Bind fragment shader outputs to the textures
glBindFragDataLocation(firstStageProgram_ID, 0, "out_diffuse");
glBindFragDataLocation(firstStageProgram_ID, 1, "out_position");
glBindFragDataLocation(firstStageProgram_ID, 2, "out_normal");

glLinkProgram(firstStageProgram_ID);

printProgramInfoLog(firstStageProgram_ID);

printError("End of linking first stage shader program");

/*
 * Get the attribute locations of the variables of the first stage vertex shader
 */
getAttributeLocation(in_normal_first_stage_ID, firstStageProgram_ID,
                     "in_normal", "first stage vertex shader");

getAttributeLocation(in_position_first_stage_ID, firstStageProgram_ID,
                     "in_position", "first stage vertex shader");

getAttributeLocation(in_color_first_stage_ID, firstStageProgram_ID,
                     "in_color", "first stage vertex shader");

getAttributeLocation(in_texCoord_first_stage_ID, firstStageProgram_ID,
                     "in_texCoord", "first stage vertex shader");

getAttributeLocation(in_intensity_first_stage_ID, firstStageProgram_ID,
                     "in_intensity", "first stage vertex shader");

getAttributeLocation(in_ambientLight_first_stage_ID, firstStageProgram_ID,
                     "in_ambientLight", "first stage vertex shader");

/*
 * Get the locations of the uniforms of the first stage vertex shader
 */
getUniformLocation(uniform_projectionMatrix_ID, firstStageProgram_ID,
                   "projectionMatrix", "first stage vertex shader");

getUniformLocation(uniform_modelMatrix_ID, firstStageProgram_ID,
                   "modelMatrix", "first stage vertex shader");

getUniformLocation(uniform_viewMatrix_ID, firstStageProgram_ID,
                   "viewMatrix", "first stage vertex shader");

getUniformLocation(uniform_mvpMatrix_first_stage_ID, firstStageProgram_ID,
                   "MVPMatrix", "first stage vertex shader");

getUniformLocation(uniform_viewportMatrix_first_stage_ID, firstStageProgram_ID,
                   "viewportMatrix", "first stage vertex shader");

/*
 * Create VAO_deferred and VBO_deffered
 */    
glGenVertexArrays (1 , &VAO_deferred); // Erzeugen des VAOs
glBindVertexArray(VAO_deferred); // Zustandsautomat: Aktiviere das VAO
glGenBuffers(4, &VBO_deferred[0]); // Erzeugen der 4 VBOs

bindBuffer(VAO_deferred, VBO_deferred[0], in_position_first_stage_ID, 4);
bindBuffer(VAO_deferred, VBO_deferred[1], in_color_first_stage_ID, 3);
bindBuffer(VAO_deferred, VBO_deferred[2], in_normal_first_stage_ID, 3);
bindBuffer(VAO_deferred, VBO_deferred[3], in_texCoord_first_stage_ID, 2);

printError("End of attaching VBO_deferred objects to first stage shader program");

// TODO: insert in_intensity and in_ambientLight into first stage vertex shader

/*
 * Deferred stage program from here
 */
createProgram(deferredStageVertex_ID, deferredStageFragment_ID, deferredStageProgram_ID,
              "shaders//DeferredStageVertexShader.glsl",
              "shaders//DeferredStageFragmentShader.glsl");

// Bind fragment shader outputs
glBindFragDataLocation(deferredStageProgram_ID, 0, "fragColor");

glLinkProgram(deferredStageProgram_ID);

printProgramInfoLog(deferredStageProgram_ID);

printError("End of linking deferred stage shader program");

getAttributeLocation(in_vertex_deferred_stage_ID, deferredStageProgram_ID,
                     "in_texture_vertex", "deferred stage vertex shader");

getUniformLocation(uniform_positionTexture_ID, deferredStageProgram_ID,
                   "positionTexture", "deferred stage vertex shader");

getUniformLocation(uniform_normalTexture_ID, deferredStageProgram_ID,
                   "normalTexture", "deferred stage vertex shader");

getUniformLocation(uniform_diffuseTexture_ID, deferredStageProgram_ID,
                   "diffuseTexture", "deferred stage vertex shader");

getUniformLocation(uniform_camera_ID, deferredStageProgram_ID, "viewMatrix", "deferred stage vertex shader");

printError("End of getting uniform locations of the deferred stage shader program");


glGenVertexArrays (1 , &VAO_texture);
glBindVertexArray(VAO_texture);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO_texture[0]);

// vertex position --> vec4
bindBuffer(VAO_texture, VBO_texture[0], in_vertex_deferred_stage_ID, 4);
```

This is my render method:

```
doLightAnimationStep();

// Create matrices
//QMatrix4x4 modelMatrix = createMouseViewMatrix();
//QMatrix4x4 mouseViewMatrix = createViewMatrix();
//QMatrix4x4 projectionMatrix = createProjectionMatrix();
QMatrix4x4 mvpMatrix = createProjectionMatrix() * createMouseViewMatrix();
QMatrix4x4 viewportMatrix = MatrixHandler::createScaleMatrix(
            10.f / scaling, 10.f / scaling, 10.f / scaling);

if(deferredShading) {
    // Bind FBO to context and clear all buffers before rendering
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FBO);
    //glViewport(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
    GLenum windowBufferSelector[] = {
        GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
        GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1,
        GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2 };
    glDrawBuffers(3, windowBufferSelector); // Select all buffers
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // Set everything to zero.
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    printError("Bound FBO and depth buffer");
    // First render stage -> writing all data into the textures and the depth buffer
    glUseProgram(firstStageProgram_ID);

    // Set uniforms
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniform_mvpMatrix_first_stage_ID, 1, GL_FALSE, mvpMatrix.data());
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniform_viewportMatrix_first_stage_ID, 1, GL_FALSE, viewportMatrix.data());

    printError("Prepared buffer 0, 1 and 2 for writing");

    //DrawTheWorld(); // Will also produce depth data in the depth buffer
    glBindVertexArray(VAO_deferred); // VAO aktivieren
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    printError("Wrote into buffer 0, 1 and 2");

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    // Deferred render stage -> read the data for all pixels from the textures and the depth buffer to calculate the color for the pixel

    // The depth buffer from stage 1 is not used now as the fbo is disabled.
    // Clearing the active buffer means clearing the screen
    glClearColor(255.0f, 255.0f, 255.0f, 0.0f); // Set everything to zero.
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    //EnableRenderProgramDeferredStage();
    glUseProgram(deferredStageProgram_ID);

    //SetupDeferredStageUniforms();
    printError("Setting uniforms for deferred stage vertex shader.");
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fDiffuseTexture);
    glUniform1i(uniform_diffuseTexture_ID, fDiffuseTexture);
    //glUniform1i(uniform_positionTexture_ID, fPositionTexture);
    //glUniform1i(uniform_normalTexture_ID, fNormalsTexture);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fNormalsTexture);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fPositionTexture);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fDiffuseTexture);

    printError("Setted uniforms for deferred stage vertex shader.");

    glBindVertexArray(VAO_texture); // VAO aktivieren
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 2);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    glUseProgram(0);

    printError("End of deffered shading rendering");
} else {
    // Enable and disable z-buffering and backface culling
    if(zBuffering) {
        if(!(glIsEnabled(GL_DEPTH_TEST) == GL_TRUE)) {
            glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        }
    } else {
        if(glIsEnabled(GL_DEPTH_TEST) == GL_TRUE) {
            glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        }
    }

    if(backfaceCulling) {
        if(!(glIsEnabled(GL_CULL_FACE) == GL_TRUE)) {
            glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        }
    } else {
        if(glIsEnabled(GL_CULL_FACE) == GL_TRUE) {
            glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        }
    }

    glClearColor(255, 255, 255, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Use shader program
    glUseProgram(program_ID);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_ID);
    glUniform1i(samplerTexture_ID, 0);

    if(textureMode == CLAMP) {
    // Werte auf kleiner 0 auf 0 beschränken , Werte größer 1 auf 1:
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    } else if(textureMode == REPEAT) {
        // Texturen wiederholen
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    } else if(textureMode == MIRRORED_REPEAT) {
        // Texturen wiederholen, die Koordinaten jedoch an den Grenzen ”spiegeln ”

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT);
    } else {
        // Should never be reached!
        assert(false);
    }

    if(filterMode == NEAREST_NEIGHBOUR) {
        // Für Nearest−Neighbor Filterung (wie im Software−Renderer)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    } else if (filterMode == LINEAR) {
        // Für Lineare Filterung (qualitativhochwertiger)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    } else if (filterMode == MIPMAPPING) {
        // Mipmapping (weniger Aliasing Artefakte, aber höherer Speicherbedarf)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    } else {
        // Should never be reached!
        assert(false);
    }

    glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrix_ID, 1, GL_FALSE, mvpMatrix.data());
    glUniformMatrix4fv(viewportMatrix_ID, 1, GL_FALSE, viewportMatrix.data());


    //float light_dist_f = (float)light_dist/100.f;
    //GLfloat lightPos__vec [3] = {light_dist_f*(float) cos(Math::toRadian(light_angle)), light_dist_f*(float) sin(Math::toRadian(light_angle)),light_dist_f};
    //glUniform3fv(lightPos_ID, 1, lightPos__vec);

    GLfloat lightPos__vec [3] = {lights[0].position.x(), lights[0].position.y(), lights[0].position.z()};
    glUniform3fv(lightPos_ID, 1, lightPos__vec);

    GLfloat intensity = ((GLfloat)light_intensity/(GLfloat)100);
    glUniform1fv(lightInt_ID, 1, &intensity);

    GLfloat ambient = ((GLfloat)light_ambient/(GLfloat)100);
    glUniform1fv(lightAmb_ID, 1, &ambient);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO); // VAO aktivieren
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0 , vertexCount);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    glUseProgram(0);
}
```

Each time I change the size of my framework I change the size of my viewport and my FBO + textures.

`sizeChanged()`:

```
// Prevent frame buffer objects to be corrupted
if(width <= 0 || height <= 0) {
    return;
}

if(origin_width == 0) {
    origin_width = width;
    origin_height = height;
}

multiplier_lr = (float)viewWidth/(float) origin_width;
multiplier_tb = (float)viewHeight/(float) origin_height;

viewWidth = width;
viewHeight = height;

screenVertices.clear();

screenVertices << 0.f << 0.f;
screenVertices << viewWidth << 0.f;
screenVertices << 0.f << viewHeight;

screenVertices << viewWidth << 0.f;
screenVertices << 0.f << viewHeight;
screenVertices << viewWidth << viewHeight;

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_texture[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * screenVertices.size(), screenVertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glViewport(0,0,width,height);

/*
 * Generate framebuffer object, renderbuffer object and color buffers
 */
// Generate framebuffer object FBO
glGenFramebuffers(1, &FBO);

// The FBO does not have a depth buffer or anything else.
// Therefore it is necessary to implement a depth buffer and all the
// texture buffers in the initialize method
// Generate and adjust depth buffer
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &fDepthBuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, fDepthBuffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, width, height);

printError("Generated frame buffer object and depth buffer");

// Generate diffuse buffer
generateTexture(fDiffuseTexture, GL_RGBA, width, height);
printError("Generated diffuse texture buffer");

// Generate and bind the texture for positions
generateTexture(fPositionTexture, GL_RGBA32F, width, height);
printError("Generated position texture buffer");

// Generate and bind the texture for normals
generateTexture(fNormalsTexture, GL_RGBA16F, width, height);
printError("Generated normal texture buffer");

// Bind the FBO so that the next operations will be bound to it.
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER , FBO);

// Attach the depth buffer to the FBO
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, fDepthBuffer);

// Attach the textures to the FBO
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, fDiffuseTexture, 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D, fPositionTexture, 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, GL_TEXTURE_2D, fNormalsTexture, 0);

printError("Bound all textures to the FBO");

// Check FBO for errors
GLenum fboStatus = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
if (fboStatus != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    printf("DeferredLighting::Init: FrameBuffer incomplete: 0x%x\n", fboStatus);
    exit(1);
}

// Unbind FBO
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER , 0);

printError("Unbound all textures to the FBO");
```

Screenvertices is a QVector, the same structure type to fill my forward shading VAO and my VAO_deferred.

First stage vertex shader:

```
#version 150

precision mediump float;

uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

uniform mat4 MVPMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewportMatrix;

in vec4 in_position;
in vec3 in_color;
in vec3 in_normal;
in vec2 in_texCoord;
in float in_intensity; // Sun light
in float in_ambient;

out vec4 position_varying;
out vec3 color_varying;
out vec3 normal_varying;
out vec2 texCoord_varying;
out float extIntensity_varying;
out float extAmbientLight_varying;


/*
 * The first stage shader program performs geometric calculations.
 * Light calculations are done in the second stage, the deferred stage shader
 * program.
 */

// Texture coordinates are applied to the first stage fragment shader.
// The normal vector is being transformed in world coordinates.
// gl_Position is being calculated with the MVP matrix in screen coordinates
// The intensity of the sun is in range [0;255], perhaps this has to be adjusted
// The ambient light is in the range of [0;255] aswell, perhaps this has to be
// adjusted too.

void main(void) {

    gl_Position = viewportMatrix * (MVPMatrix * in_position);
    color_varying = in_color;
    normal_varying = in_normal;
    texCoord_varying = in_texCoord;

    // Not used right now
    //extIntensity_varying = in_intensity;
    //extAmbientLight_varying = in_ambient;

    /*
    normal_varying = normalize((modelMatrix*vec4(in_normal, 0.0)));
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * in_vertex;
    position_varying = vec3(modelMatrix * in_vertex); // Copy position to the fragment shader
    extIntensity_varying = in_intensity/255.0; // Scale the intensity from [0..255] to [0..1].
    extAmbientLight_varying = in_ambientLight/255.0;
    */
}
```

First stage fragment shader:

```
#version 150

precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D firstTexture;

in vec4 position_varying; // The model coordinate, as given by the vertex shader
in vec3 color_varying; // The interpolated color of the fragment
in vec3 normal_varying; // The interpolated normal of the fragment
in vec2 texCoord_varying; // The interpolated texture coordinates of the fragment

// To be written into texture buffers
out vec4 out_position;  // layout(location = 0)
out vec3 out_normal;    // layout(location = 1)
out vec3 out_diffuse;   // layout(location = 2)

/*
 * The first stage shader program performs geometric calculations.
 * Light calculations are done in the second stage, the deferred stage shader
 * program.
 */

// Output the model-transformed vertex-coordinates
// Output normal (normalized)
void main(void) {
    out_position = position_varying; // Position given by the vertext shader
    out_normal = normal_varying;
    out_diffuse = color_varying;

    /*
    // The blending is not necessary in calculation with the GDV framework
    // as there are no transparent models
    vec4 clr = texture(firstTexture, texCoord_varying);
    out_diffuse = clr;
    */
}
```

Deferred stage vertex shader:

```
#version 150

precision mediump float;

in vec2 in_texture_vertex;

out vec2 texture_varying;

/*
 * The first stage shader program performs geometric calculations.
 * Light calculations are done in the second stage, the deferred stage shader
 * program.
 */

void main(void) {

    // Why is there a calculation in_vertex*2-1?
    gl_Position = vec4(in_texture_vertex.xy, 0.f, 0.f);

    // Copy position to the fragment shader. Only x and y is needed.
    texture_varying = in_texture_vertex;
}
```

Deferred stage fragment shader:

```
#version 150

precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D positionTexture; // World position
uniform sampler2D normalTexture;   // Normals
uniform sampler2D diffuseTexture;  // The color information

// Not used?
//uniform vec3 camera;          // The coordinate of the camera

in vec2 texture_varying;     // The world position

out vec4 fragColor;           // layout(location = 0)

/*
 * The first stage shader program performs geometric calculations.
 * Light calculations are done in the second stage, the deferred stage shader
 * program.
 */

void main(void) {
    // Load data, stored in textures, from the first stage rendering.

    // Color
    fragColor = texture2D(diffuseTexture, texture_varying);
    //fragColor = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);

    //vec4 worldPos = texture(positionTexture, texture_varying.xy);

    // Normals
    //fragColor = texture(normalTexture, texture_varying.xy);

    // Use information about lamp coordinate (not shown here), the pixel
    // coordinate (worldpos.xyz), the normal of this pixel (normal.xyz)
    // to compute a lighting effect.
    // Use this lighting effect to update 'diffuse'
    //vec4 preBlend = diffuse * lamp + specularGlare;
    //fragColor = (normal+1)/2;
    //fragColor = diffuse;
    //fragColor = worldPos; // Scaling may be needed to range [0,1]
    //fragColor = lamp*vec4(1,1,1,1);
}
```

Comment: One thing I noticed is this draw call: `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 2)`. Specifying 2 vertices for drawing triangles will render nothing. Not sure if this is the only problem. There's a lot of code, and I haven't looked at all of it. Another thing to look out for is that you set the filter mode on all the textures before you sample from them in the second pass.

Comment: You were right, this was one of the errors.
I figured it out and now it is working, but I will explain:

- Be sure to draw 3 or more vertices for drawing a triangle!
- Bind your texture and after that set your uniform like the following:
`glUniform1i(uniform_diffuseTexture_ID, 0);`
and not something like
`glUniform1i(uniform_diffuseTexture_ID, myTexture);`
- For deferred shading think about your coordinates in the second shader stage! Be sure you have got homogenous coordinates and calculate them like below:
`gl_Position = -1 + 2 * vec4(in_texture_vertex.xy, 0.f, 1.f);`